# Routing request to multiple services based on baseURI

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have multiple services running under `Nginx`. All these services are on different ports.

How can I redirect a request to particular service based on initial `base URI` ?

e.g. for URL `https://my-domain/serviceA/v1/schema` to port `8181` as `/v1/schema`
and `https://my-domain/serviceB/v1/api/schema` to port `9191` as `/v1/api/schema`.

Until now I have am able to forward the request using `location` to particular port based on initial path but not able to remove `/serviceA` or `/serviceB` from `URI`.

Comment: There is an example in the documentation for the [`proxy_pass` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that way:

  location /serviceA {
    proxy_pass http://10.5.121.6:8181;
   ....
 some other config...
 ......
}

but the problem in that is that it is not removing "/serviceA/" form the URL as per the documentation if I provide it like 

location /serviceA/v1 {
    proxy_pass http://10.5.121.6:8181/v1;
   ....
 some other config...
 ......
}

then it would replace the url.

Answer (score 0):

The `proxy_pass` statement can include an optional URI component. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location /serviceA/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:8080/;
    ...
}
```

The URI component is the final `/` on the `proxy_pass` statement. The URI `/serviceA/foo` is translated to `/foo` before passing upstream. Use a trailing `/` on the `location` value for correct translation.